# ion-slides: vertical align content in center of slide. How to?

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic4

I would like to vertical align the content on each slide in the center of the screen. But it seems there is no way to style the css of the ion-slides in a way that my content is vertically aligned in the center.

I tried various ways, but none had an impact on the slides.

```
<ion-slide>
 <h2>Date of Birth</h2>
 <p>Please select</p>
 <ion-item>
  <ion-datetime formControlName="birthday" displayFormat="DD- 
  MM-YYYY" picker-format="DD-MM-YYYY" cancelText="Cancel" 
  doneText="Done" placeholder="Day-Month-Year">
  </ion-datetime>
 </ion-item>
</ion-slide>
```

And CSS i tried:

```
.slide-container {
    vertical-align: center !important;
}
```

or..

```
.slides {
    display: flex !important;
    justify-content: center !important;
    align-items: center !important;
    height: 100%;
}
```

How can I overwrite the ion-slides css, so that the content of the slide is perfectly in the middle of the screen?

Answer (score -1):

Make sure your ion-slides have enough height

```
ion-slide{ height: 80vh;}
```

I use 80vh with `<ion-header>`, but without `<ion-header>` you can use 100vh.

If you still want to make it middle you can use

```
ion-slide{ 
position: relative; 
top:50%;
transform: translate(0,-50%); 
}
```

[image]